# SQL server while transaction is opened

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am using SQL server 2014 management studio.
I am working on a windows form application (vb.net).

I am facing a problem. (I am not sure if it works this way)

I wrote some Database insertion inline queries. 
While I Debug my code, SQL transaction is open and inserting the data,

My question here is that if a transaction is opened from back-end, why can I not execute any query from management studio?

As soon as transaction is committed or rolled back, management studio works fine with even big queries too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is a good explanation of this here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/#comment-2220427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a transaction, the objects used in the transaction are locked and no other connection is allowed to access the object. In your case when you run the transaction within the application the transaction locks the objects being used (like table) and simultaneously when you fire query from management studio it waits for the lock to be released. As soon as the transaction in the application completes lock is released and the query in the management studio executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `with nolock` in Your query.
It will allow you to acces the data from object included in transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using different IDEs, the Sql server instance you are using is the same. You are accessing the same Database no matter from which IDE you are accessing.